# Write to a file android

Tags: android, file

I am trying to write some date data in a file with with function:

```
public void writeSettings(Context context, String data){

             FileOutputStream fOut = null;
             OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
             try {       
                 fOut = openFileOutput("settings.dat",MODE_PRIVATE);      
                 osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                 osw.write(data);
                 osw.flush();
                 Toast.makeText(context, "Settings saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
              }

              catch (Exception e) {      
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  Toast.makeText(context, "Settings not saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
              }
              finally {
                 try {
                        osw.close();
                        fOut.close();

                 } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        }

              }

         }
```

In the blog where I found this code, it is said my file is stored in:
`/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/files/settings.dat`

But I cannot find it on my phone! Where is this `data` folder?

Comment: please download any file manager from market

Answer (score 1):

In phone (Device) you don't have root privileges,so you can't see `/data/data/` directory using `eclipse->DDMS->File Explorer`,

SO if you want to just see whether your file is created or not you can use `./adb shell` command (for linux) `adb shell` (for windows)

Or try this on **emulator** and check with `eclipse -> DDMS -> File Explorer`...

Answer (score 0):

You don not have access to /data folder in your phone unless you have root privileges.
You can test your app in emulator, data folder in emulator is accessable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add permissions WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS and/or WRITE_SETTINGS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse ide, find DDMS Window and click File Explorer.  Search for /data/data/Package_Name/files